# Add tag with content to existing XML (resx) using python

Tags: python, xml, resx

I have an XML with a number of strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Strings>
    <String id="TEST_STRING_FROM_XML">
      <en>Test string from XML</en>
      <de>Testzeichenfolge aus XML</de>
      <es>Cadena de prueba de XML</es>
      <fr>Tester la chaîne à partir de XML</fr>
      <it>Stringa di test da XML</it>
      <ja>XMLからのテスト文字列</ja>
      <ko>XML에서 테스트 문자열</ko>
      <nl>Testreeks van XML</nl>
      <pl>Łańcuch testowy z XML</pl>
      <pt>Cadeia de teste de XML</pt>
      <ru>Тестовая строка из XML</ru>
      <sv>Teststräng från XML</sv>
      <zh-CHS>从XML测试字符串</zh-CHS>
      <zh-CHT>從XML測試字符串</zh-CHT>
      <Comment>A test string that comes from a shared XML file.</Comment>
    </String>
    <String id="TEST_STRING_FROM_XML_2">
      <en>Another test string from XML.</en>
      <de></de>
      <es></es>
      <fr></fr>
      <it></it>
      <ja></ja>
      <ko></ko>
      <nl></nl>
      <pl></pl>
      <pt></pt>
      <ru></ru>
      <sv></sv>
      <zh-CHS></zh-CHS>
      <zh-CHT></zh-CHT>
      <Comment>Another test string that comes from a shared XML file.</Comment>
    </String>
  </Strings>
```

And I would like to append these strings to a resx file with a long list of strings in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <!-- 
    Microsoft ResX Schema 
    
    Version 2.0
    
    **a bunch of schema and header stuff...**
    -->
    
  <data name="STRING_NAME_1" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This is a value 1</value>
    <comment>This is a comment 1</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="STRING_NAME_2" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This is a value 2</value>
    <comment>This is a comment 2</comment>
  </data>
</root>
```

But using the following snippet of python code:

```
import sys, os, os.path, re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

existingStrings = []
newStrings = {}
languages = []

resx = '*path to resx file*'


def LoadAllNewStrings():

    src_root = ET.parse('Strings.xml').getroot()

    for src_string in src_root.findall('String'):

        src_id = src_string.get('id')

        src_value = src_string.findtext("en")
        src_comment = src_string.findtext("Comment")

        content = [src_value, src_comment]

        newStrings[src_id] = content


def ExscludeExistingStrings():
    dest_root = ET.parse(resx)
    for stringName in dest_root.findall('Name'):
        for stringId in newStrings:
            if stringId == stringName:
                newStrings.remove(stringId)


def PrettifyXML(element):

    roughString = ET.tostring(element, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(roughString)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")


def AddMissingStringsToLocalResource():

    ExscludeExistingStrings()
    
    with open(resx, "a") as output:
        root = ET.parse(resx).getroot()

        for newString in newStrings:
            
            data = ET.Element("data", name=newString)

            newStringContent = newStrings[newString]
            newStringValue = newStringContent[0]
            newStringComment = newStringContent[1]

            ET.SubElement(data, "value").text = newStringValue
            ET.SubElement(data, "comment").text = newStringComment

            output.write(PrettifyXML(data))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoadAllNewStrings()
    AddMissingStringsToLocalResource()
```

I get the following XML appended to the end of the resx file:

```
  <data name="STRING_NAME_2" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This is a value 1</value>
    <comment>This is a comment 1</comment>
  </data>
</root><?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data name="TEST_STRING_FROM_XML">
  <value>Test string from XML</value>
  <comment>A test string that comes from a shared XML file.</comment>
</data>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data name="TEST_STRING_FROM_XML_2">
  <value>Another test string from XML.</value>
  <comment>Another test string that comes from a shared XML file.</comment>
</data>
```

I.e. the root ends and then my new strings are added after. Any ideas on how to add the data tags to the existing root properly?

Comment: Your code shows strong hints of being copypasted uncritically from multiple sources. The fact that you have both ElementTree and Minidom in there is a dead giveaway. You don't need 2 DOM parsers. Throw one out. Rewrite the code that depends on the second one. Basically - rewrite everything, so you understand what it does.

Answer (score 1):

> `with open(resx, "a") as output:`

**No.** Don't open XML files as text files. Not for reading, not for writing, not for appending. Never.

The typical life cycle of an XML file is:

- parsing (with an XML parser)
- reading or Modification (with a DOM API)
- if there were changes: Serializition (also with a DOM API)

At no point should you ever call `open()` on an XML file. XML files are not supposed to be treated as if they were plain text. They are not.

```
# parsing
resx = ET.parse(resx_path)
root = resx.getroot()

# modification
for newString in newStrings:
    newStringContent = newStrings[newString]

    # create node
    data = ET.Element("data", name=newString)
    ET.SubElement(data, "value").text = newStringContent[0]
    ET.SubElement(data, "comment").text = newStringContent[1]
    
    # append node, e.g. to the top level element
    root.append(data)
    
# serialization
resx.write(resx_path, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Alright, that seems to work. Although I lose some resx specific format at the beginning of the file - but that's not a huge issue.
How would you go about pretty printing this, as to not have it all spat out into one line?

Comment: My personal view is this - When you read XML exclusively through a DOM API, the layout of the file itself becomes irrelevant. That was one of the design goals if DOM APIs after all. .NET - which will consume the resx file here, I presume - certainly does not care one bit. But the reality is that many people want to or need to edit XML manually and pretty printing becomes an issue. Some DOM APIs, such as `lxml`, offer built-in pretty printing support. Others, such as Python's `ElementTree` don't offer it out of the box, but people have written functions for that.